# How to avoid duplicate key error with django allauth?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-allauth

I have made some changes to my user model and as a result it seems that when a new user tries to sign up they receive the error:

```
IntegrityError at /accounts/signup/
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_user_username_key"
```

I am not sure what is causing the error

This is the forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model, forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

User = get_user_model()


class UserChangeForm(forms.UserChangeForm):
    class Meta(forms.UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = User


class UserCreationForm(forms.UserCreationForm):

    error_message = forms.UserCreationForm.error_messages.update(
        {
            "duplicate_username": _(
                "This username has already been taken."
            )
        }
    )

    class Meta(forms.UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]

        try:
            User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username

        raise ValidationError(
            self.error_messages["duplicate_username"]
        )
```

settings.py

```
# django-allauth
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACCOUNT_ALLOW_REGISTRATION = env.bool(
    "DJANGO_ACCOUNT_ALLOW_REGISTRATION", True
)
# https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "username"
# https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
# https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
# https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = "pharmhand.users.adapters.AccountAdapter"
# https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = (
    "pharmhand.users.adapters.SocialAccountAdapter"
)

# Your stuff...
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'users.forms.UserCreationForm'
```

And the models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class User(AbstractUser):

    # First Name and Last Name Do Not Cover Name Patterns
    # Around the Globe.
    name = models.CharField(
        _("Name of User"), blank=True, max_length=255
    )

    title = models.CharField(
        _("Title"), null=True, max_length=10, default='Dr'
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(
        _("First Name"), null=True, max_length=255, default='test'
    )

    last_name = models.CharField(
        _("Last Name"), null=True, max_length=255, default='Test'
    )

    job_title = models.CharField(
        _("Job Title"), null=True, max_length=255, default='Test'
    )

    address1 = models.CharField(
        _("Address 1"), null=True, max_length=255, default='Test'
    )

    address2 = models.CharField(
        _("Address 2"), null=True, max_length=255, default='Test'
    )

    address3 = models.CharField(
        _("Address 3"), null=True, max_length=255, default='Test'
    )

    city = models.CharField(
        _("City"), null=True, max_length=255, default='Test'
    )

    post_code = models.CharField(
        _("Post Code"), null=True, max_length=255, default='Test'
    )

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            "users:detail", kwargs={"username": self.username}
        )
```

Any advice on how to avoid the error much appreciated, I don't know if perhaps things are complicated by the hybrid contrib.auth allauth approach

Comment: From their github issues page: If you are receiving a sporadic IntegrityError it may be the case that the same request is being fired twice, for example due to the user accidentally double clicking the signup button. You may want to try disabling the submit button using a bit of JS...

Comment: This isnt real users- just me testing, happens everytime i try to signup

Comment: Do you use signals for the User model??

Comment: @EneP Thankyou, I don't believe so - the model code is in the question

Answer (score 0):

The problems was

`ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'users.forms.UserCreationForm'`

I had added this in order to be able to edit the signup form (which it made possible), but had the side effect I think of both the allauth and contrib.auth trying to create a user leading to the error. Removing the line fixed the error (Although Im still trying to figure out how to edit the fields for the signupform)